# How to backup and restore downloaded gnome-shell extensions?

Tags: gnome, backup, gnome-shell-extension

I have downloaded several gnome-shell extensions from official Gnome site and installed. But, I don't want to install them every time, I re-install my Ubuntu. I want to have a feature to backup those extensions and restore them  as required.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The downloaded gnome-shell extensions are stored in the `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder in your home directory folder. Copy the extensions folder and store them in somewhere else.

When you need to restore those extensions, copy and paste the stored `extensions` folder in your `.local/share/gnome-shell` folder. Logout and Login.

Comment: Simply copying the extensions folder didn't work for me (Ubuntu Gnome Shell Remix 12.04)

Comment: I had to enable each extension.

Answer (score 8):

I guess I figured it out. You have to replace (after backuping, for safety) the following three folders with the original ones previously saved from the system you want to clone:

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/quicklaunch`

`~/.config/dconf`

Then logout and login.

Let me know if it works, or if you find better ways!

(tested on Ubuntu Gnome Shell Remix 12.04)

Comment: I have to replace those folders with what?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way so far is to use the [chrome connector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep).

All you have to do is to right click the extensions, go to options and make sure "Synchronize GNOME Shell extensions list" is enabled. After you reinstall ubuntu you need to install this chrome extensions again and disable/re-enable this sync options. You will be prompted which extension list to use, remote or local and you can chose the remote list.

Only caveat i have found so far is that the extensions settings are not backed up too.

Comment: The connector is available for other browsers as well, despite the misleading name: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation

Comment: If you're wondering where to find the Sync functionality, it is hidden inside the extension options (Chrome version). Works like a charm; thank you Mihai!

Answer (score 0):

gnome extensions are there : `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` (`sudo cp` obviously)

to reinstall you copy them back in `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` (you'll need to reactivate them in gnome tweak & then restart the session though)